# R source feature that connects function brackets

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

I observed this feature during a webinar and was curious how to initiate it.

[image]

The screenshot is not the best, but I'm interested in turning on the feature where vertical lines connect function brackets. Anyone know how I turn on this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the code editor being used; I can't figure out what it is from the photo. In RStudio, you can get a similar feature if you go to "Tools -> Global Options", in the left menu choose "Code", on the top choose the "Display" tab, and activate the option "Show indent guides".